# Is there a way to redraw a TextInputLayout’s OutlinedBox?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to use android hint programmatically to exploit the top stroke of the OutlinedBox in an input validation, using

`binding.firstQuantity.hint="Enter a valid number"`  and it worked fine:

[Validation message in OutlinedBox top stroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEM5J.png)

But when the hint is cleared with

`binding.firstQuantity.hint=""`  part of the top stroke is lost :

[Part of the OutlinedBox top stroke is lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yozEx.png)

Is there a way to “redraw” the OutlinedBox?

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a bug, unless they intentionally meant for us to not be able to do that. `TextInputLayout` will only recalculate the cutout dimensions if the hint is enabled and not empty, so as soon as we try to set either of those values, it can never reach the method necessary to close the cutout. The simplest straightforward solution might just be to create a new `TextInputLayout`/`EditText` instance whenever you need to clear the hint. Otherwise, we can do something with reflection; e.g., https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E05Tjw9O4dBqthiYrKXnMbVrqbn2VswW/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: I just realized that we should be able to do this without reflection. I added an alternate solution to that Drive file, but I haven't really tested it much yet.