# Android TextInputLayout hint gets bugged when recycled by a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-textinputlayout

**USE CASE**

I have a `RecyclerView` whose `ViewHolder` contains a `TextInputLayout`. For some situations I want it to display a `hint` and for other situations I don't.

**ISSUE**

When the `RecyclerView` recycles a `ViewHolder` that has previously displayed a `hint` but on the new `bind` does not require a `hint`. It will display an **empty hint** instead. See picture:

[Image for NOT recycled ViewHolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmEN3.png)

[Image for recycled ViewHolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DecQQ.png)

The problem seems to happen ONLY if the new binding has NO `hint`. If I set a `hint` to every `ViewHolder` with different values, it recycles and displays correctly.

**Snippet**

Adapter.kt

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FormViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind(getItem(position))
}
```

ViewHolder.kt

```
override fun onBind(model: Model) {
    binding.inputLayout.isHintEnabled = model.hasHint
    binding.inputLayout.isHintAnimationEnabled = model.hasHint
    binding.inputLayout.hint = model.hintValue
}
```

I tried:

- Updating to latest version ATM: `com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0`

Comment: This sounds like it might be the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74118993. I have a couple of possible workarounds linked there.

Comment: No problem. Btw, if you had any issues getting those suggested solutions working, I've since updated them. The `TextInputLayout` class changed a bit, apparently. Just FYI. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextInputLayout will only recalculate the cutout dimensions if the hint is enabled and not empty, so as soon as we try to set either of those values, it can never reach the method necessary to close the cutout. The simplest straightforward solution might just be to create a new TextInputLayout/EditText instance whenever you need to clear the hint. Otherwise, we can do something with reflection

[Is there a way to redraw a TextInputLayout’s OutlinedBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74118993/is-there-a-way-to-redraw-a-textinputlayout-s-outlinedbox#comment130864812_74118993)

Thanks to @Mike.M for the answer

Answer (score 0):

i don't see problems in your code, so, of course it sounds like a bug, but you can try:

1. set focus.
2. set text color.
3. invoke invalidate() on text input layout in onBind viewholder method.

and see how the system reacts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It turned out to be a bug on the component. Thanks to @Mike.M for the answer